# CoreMidi Hex values

Tags: ios, midi, coremidi

I am trying to send a next track message to Logic Pro from my ios app. This is the hex value for "play" {0xF0, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x06, 0x02, 0xF7}. Does anyone know the hex value for "Next track"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "play" message is a [MIDI Machine Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI_Machine_Control) message.

That standard does not define a "next track" message.
The neareast would be "fast forward": `F0 7F 7F 06 04 F7`.